# What's wrong w/my formula in poi HSSFCell setCellFormula?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to set a simple formula in a spreadsheet that just subtracts the value of one cell from another. This is the relevant code snippet.

```
residentialCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
residentialCell.setCellFormula(formula);
```

This is the error I get when it runs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Unused input [E] after attempting to parse the formula [2E-8E]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1573)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:176)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.HSSFFormulaParser.parse(HSSFFormulaParser.java:72)
```

The formula should be "2E-8E" like it says. This seems simple enough, so sorry if I'm overlooking something that should be obvious to me. I've googled this for quite a while, and all the examples I've found seem to suggest that this should work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the formula you are using, please

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem, then feel free to accept that answer by clicking the checkmark.  That, rather than editing in "Solved", is the customary way in StackOverflow to indicate that the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have your row/column designation backwards.  Assuming that it's part of a larger formula, your probably want `"E2-E8"` instead of `"2E-8E"`.

The error indicates that whatever parsed this part recognized "2E-8" as a valid floating-point literal number, with an extra "E" that can't be parsed as anything meaningful.